# floating action button overlapping one over other

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

i am trying to create a floating action buttons in my app, i added two floating action buttons, but the problem is they appear on top of each other.
  I am using fragments, does it matter if its fragments? can somebody please point out what wrong i am doing. I am using the coordinator layout and inside that i am using  Relative layout. at the end of it i am using floating action buttons. Here is the code snippet

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
tools:context="com.saibaba.myapplication.MainFragment">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" /> 


  </RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_share"
    android:layout_width="352dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_share"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/mainFragment"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_plus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_plus"
    app:backgroundTint="#FF0000"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/mainFragment"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `android:layout_margin` in  your code , the other `android:layout_marginBottom` 、`android:layout_marginLeft` 、`android:layout_marginRight`、`android:layout_marginTop` will have no effect .

Remove

```
android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
```

Comment: Good  luck to you.@User5144